# NodeJs creating table in mysql DB

Tags: mysql

Im trying to create a table called product in my DB, but I keep getting an error that says module not found. Can anyone help me? My code is below

```
// include mysql module
var mysql = require('mysql');

//MySQL DB Connection 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database: 'jordanRack'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connection Succeeded!")

    // create product table
  var sql = "CREATE TABLE product (prod_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, imagePath VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, prod_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, price INT NOT NULL, size INT NOT NULL)";

  // if query goes through
  connection.query( sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Table created");
  });
  });
```

Comment: did you install the driver with npm install mysql

Comment: Yes I did. Im connected to the mysql server already so that piece is fine. The problem is I cant create a table in the DB.

Comment: i can't imagine, where your error message comes from, when the install was without error. can you do any other commands?

Comment: I fixed it, I wasn't include my module in my app.js file. I had to include: 
var prod = require('./tables/product');

one more question, im now trying to include data in that table, but can I now delete that file because Im getting an error saying db already exist because the file is there and running on every server start up.

Comment: Delete it or if you wnat to deploy your program use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, so that won't gove an error.